# How to implement DaisyUI to React Native

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css, daisyui

I made a website with [Symfony](https://symfony.com/) and [DaisyUI](https://daisyui.com/), i want to extend it and create mobile versions, could i use components i made on my website ?
I know [NativeWind](https://www.nativewind.dev/) exists to use Tailwind on RN, but doesn't implement DaisyUI.
I don't know much of RN.

I already tried to create RN app, implement Tailwind.
Not a lot of solutions on internet.

Thanks

Comment: [Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MattiaRighetti Thanks for your answer, i asked a question if it is possible to implement DaisyUI into RN and how do it, i don't know what to reproduce

Comment: @rrr63 did you end up figuring it out? I'm looking to do this too

Comment: @Bash Unfortunly not, I used to use tailwind native

Comment: @rrr63 Yeah I tried installing it too and immediately got an error when adding the btn class. Even if it worked it isn't meant for RN, the 3rd version especially is meant to be used with specific html tags anyways. I'm going to try out Tamagui as an alternative

Comment: @Bash Thanks for the alternative, i will check this